# Weird result of CHARINDEX of SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014. I have the following statement:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('C', 'ABCDEFGC', 3);
```

The result I get is `3` instead of `8`. I observe the same behavior with different strings. Is this expected behavior of this function?

It seems fine if the last parameter is any other number.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not weird at all, that's how [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) works. The third parameter you pass in is the start position to start searching for your expression.

You'll have to deal with this a lot if you're using CHARINDEX along with [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) to find text in between two expressions.

If you start searching AT the CHARINDEX of C in your example, you get the same results.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('C', 'ABCDEFGC', CHARINDEX('C', 'ABCDEFGC'));
```

Returns 3

You need to start searching for the CHARINDEX one position *after* to get the next one. Otherwise, it finds the searched expression in the first position it checks.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('C', 'ABCDEFGC', CHARINDEX('C', 'ABCDEFGC') + LEN('C'));
```

Returns 8

If you start searching *after* the last occurrence, CHARINDEX will wrap back around.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('C', 'ABCDEFGC', CHARINDEX('C', 'ABCDEFGC', 9));
```

Also returns 3.

Hope this helps!